# Collapse List<List<String>> into List<String> using a lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Say I have a list of Lists..

```
List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
```

Is there a clever lambda way to collapse this into a List of all the contents ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's what flatMap is for :

```
List<String> list = inputList.stream() // create a Stream<List<String>>
                             .flatMap(l -> l.stream()) // create a Stream<String>
                                                       // of all the Strings in
                                                       // all the internal lists
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Looks like you answer all the flatMap questions. :-) Note the lambda could also be replaced with `List::stream`.

Comment: This answers is very usefully

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
List<String> result = lists.stream()
    .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Don't think this will work--the argument of `flatMap` has to be a function that turns a `List<String>` into a `Stream<String>`.  See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: @ajb : Taking another look to the `Function.identity()` doc, you are right. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
        Let's say you have list of list of person names as below
        [[John, Wick], [Patric, Peter], [Nick, Bill]]
    */
    List<List<String>> personsNames =
            List.of(List.of("John", "Wick"), List.of("Patric", "Peter"), List.of("Nick", "Bill"));

    List<String> finalList = personsNames
            .stream()
            .flatMap(name -> name.stream()).collect(toList());
    
    /*
    * Final result will be like - [John, Wick, Patric, Peter, Nick, Bill]
    */
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<String> result = lists.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```